# Error in Automapper when using IncludeMembers

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map between two objects, **Request** to a **RequestDto** using Automapper 9.0 with *IncludeMembers()*, however I always get the following message:

*Property 'Person' is not defined for type 'Request'*

I understand the error message, because that property is not defined and know that i can use `ForMember` on every property, but i would like to use `IncludeMembers()`. How do i configure Automapper so my objects are mapped?

```
public class RequestDto
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
}

public class Request
{
  public SearchFields SearchFields {get;set;}
}

public class SearchFields 
{
  public Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

Mapping Code

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>()
    .IncludeMembers(m=>m.SearchFields, m=>m.Searchfields.Person);
CreateMap<Person, RequestDto>(MemberList.None); 
CreateMap<SearchFields, RequestDto>(Memberlist.None);
```

Comment: `CreateMap<SearchFields, RequestDto>().IncludeMembers(s=>s.Person);`

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3249

Comment: Cool, so it's fixed, but will be in a future release?

Comment: Go with my workaround. It looks better.

Comment: For me example just works with the same automapper version(9.0.0). But I have the same problem when I try to configure similar nested mappings for WCF DataContracts it looks like nested source memebrs for .IncludeMembers somethimes works, some times doenst work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>()
     .ForMember(x => x.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.SearchFields.Person.FirstName));
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because there is no `RequestDto.Person` property, only `RequestDto.FirstName` (and 15 more properties), so i was hoping not to have to do `ForMember` for all properties

Comment: Correct. Edited my answer.

Comment: I know this will work, but i was hoping to use the new `IncludeMembers` method in AutoMapper, so i dont have to map all 15 properties with `ForMember`

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that Lucian Bargaoanu wanted to say: You need to create a map for each level of nested member:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>()
    .IncludeMembers(m=>m.SearchFields);
CreateMap<Searchfields, RequestDto>()
    .IncludeMembers(m=>m.Person, m=>m.Searchfields.Person);
```

instead of:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>()
    .IncludeMembers(m=>m.SearchFields, m=>m.Searchfields.Person);
```

Anyways for me, nested members work (automapper 9.0.0) for examples including example in uestion but not for WCF DataContract

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.